# How to retrieve values from parent page to modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have this textbox and an image button wherein it will display a modal dialog. When I choose a value in the modal dialog and close it (or click "Ok"), the selected value is displayed in the textbox. But when I click again the image button, my selected value is not displayed in the modal dialog.

Any ideas on how to retrieved my selected value when I click my image button?

**UPDATE**

The value which is passed from the parent is stored in the `window.ModalPopUp.data('params')` method. That one is already settled. But what I'm having trouble with is how to get the value from that to work in the server side. Here's code section in the `Page_Load` event.

```
'Bind the selected items
' TODO: Insert some code here to retrieve values from the window.ModalPopUp.data() method and pass to the SelectedValues hidden field

Dim arrSelectedValues() As String = Nothing
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedValues.Value) = False Then
     arrSelectedValues = Split(SelectedValues.Value, ",")
End If
MultiValue.Value = arrSelectedValues
```

And here is my section for the jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.ModalPopUp.data('params')) {

        var result = window.ModalPopUp.data('params');
        $("#SelectedValues").val(result);
    }
});
```

Hope you can help me with this...

Comment: Yes, I have plenty of ideas but without your code, trying to answer your question would be like trying to find a needle in a haystack wearing a blindfold.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker: It is from different areas of the application. I'm currently looking into the modal dialog where it has this window.parent.returnValue which is set. But I want to know where should I start?

Comment: Store the value you want for the modal, then when the modal has opened or even before, change the value of the modal.

Comment: parent.document.getelementbyid('your textbox id').value since the value is already in the text box.

Comment: @ShashankChaturvedi: How about if there are multiple textbox ids? I just found out that per page, it has different place where it is stored. Example: Page 1 stores the value from the modal in Textbox 1; Page 2 stores the value from the modal in Textbox 2; Page 3 stores the value from the modal in Textbox 3. Something like that.